# How can you test for &amp; in URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, replace, query-string

Our project management system has an Outlook plugin that's triggering &amp ; (space after &amp added purposely for this post) in the URLs, where it should only be the ampersand itself (&). How can I write a script that detects that and converts it properly? Here's what I have so far, but it doesn't like the &amp ; apparently.

```
querystring.replace('&amp;', '&');
```

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `decodeURI` or `decodeURIComponent`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent

Comment: @M1K1O That's for decoding percent-encodings in URIs, not HTML entities.

Comment: @RobertHarvey This is not URL encoding, it's an HTML entity.

Comment: In that case: https://gist.github.com/yidas/797c9e6d5c856158cffd685b8a8b4ee4